# matplotlib histogram and actual frequencies don't match

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame with a Series called 'Age'. To that DataFrame, I appended another Series called 'Age Group," binned as follows:

```
bins = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65]
df['Age Group'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins)
```

Now, I've verified that the age groups, for instanced (40, 45] and (45, 50] should present frequencies of 5 and 10, respectively. However, the pyplot histogram presents the wrong frequencies (2 and 13, respectively...three below and three above). I'm sure this is a left/right bin boundary issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Can someone help? My visualization code is below.

```
plt.hist(df['Age'], bins=bins, ec='gray', alpha=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.hist` uses `[a,b)` while `pd.cut` uses `(a,b]`, passing `right=False` to `pd.cut` would give the same answers as `plt.hist`.

Comment: Thanks, but then, the histogram gives an inaccurate representation. Is there a way to ensure the histogram is accurate?

Comment: You can do `bins=np.array(bins) + 0.01`. You can also view the bins with `pd.cut(df['Age'],bins=bins).value_counts().plot.bar()`...

Comment: That works! Thanks! Do you know why 0.01 needs to be added? It makes intuitive sense...boundary conditions.

Comment: because  `[40.01, 45.01) == (40,45] == {41,42,43,44,45}` in terms of integers. Of course it doesn't work if `Age` aren't integers :-).

Comment: Wonderful; thanks again!